# getDoctrine() null on Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an error on a symfony 3.4 project.
I'm trying to manage the display of a notification in the menu of my application.
So I created a CustomController which extends Controller.

Then I made all my other controllers inherit from CustomController.

But when I make a call to getDoctrine() to reach a repository I get the following error:

"Call to a member function has() on null"

Here is my CustomController:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class CustomController extends Controller
{
    public $data = [];
    protected $em;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $countAttente = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Commandes')->tailleEnAttente("En attente");
        
        $this->data['countAttente'] = $countAttente;
    }
}
```

I tried to pass the controller as a service in service.yml but it did not change anything

```
AppBundle\Controller\CustomController:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\CustomController
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

I found many similar topics on this type of error but none of them allowed me to skip this error

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowire your EntityManager directly inside your constructor:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

Or if you need a specific repository, and autowired is set up with the default configuration you can do the same as well with the repository:

```
private $repository;

public function __construct(CommandesRepository $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
}
```